# Using average to calculate half

Tags: arithmetic

If 1 kid can eat 5 candies, 2 kids can eat 11 candies and 3 kids can eat 25 candies, then how much can 2.5 kids eat?

I was thinking you calculate the average then use that but I cant just use the average right? I was thinking the average was equal to 2 kids and then add the .5 but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: You could do a linear regression, but I would say half a kid can't eat any candy

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are these six different kids with different candy-eating capabilities, and you're supposed to estimate the amount of candy that a randomly selected "two-and-a-half" of them can eat?

Comment: Seems silly, but you can fit a quadratic to these points.  You get $p(x)=4 x^2 - 6 x + 7$.  Then you can evaluate that at $x=2.5$ to get $17$ if you want, though what it means....

Comment: Yeah, it is a silly way to put it. I just got some reference material and it doesn't seem right but I cant figure it out. I can use 2.5 as a reference point for consumption but I only have the data for consumption for 1, 2, and 3 units. The example I have uses the average as an equivalent for 2.5 unit but is that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Depends on whether or not it's the half with the mouth.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Depending on how the kid is cut, not only would he be able up eat the candy, but you may be able to recycle it for further consumption. Authoritative references: https://youtu.be/G1QAt4bgwys and https://youtu.be/ZdctwUTybfE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what mean you are aiming for, arithmetic, geometric, harmonic, etc. In this case, I'd suggest arithmetic mean. So, we have 6 kids, eating 41 candies. So the arithmetic mean ( average), any one kid ate, is $${41\over 6}=6+{5\over 6}$$ candies  per child. This makes: $$(6+{5\over 6})\cdot (2+{1\over 2})=  12+3+(1+{4\over 6})+{5\over 12}= 17 +{2\over 12} $$ candies for two and a half children.

Of course It depends on how you interpret the question.  The ambiguous word is **can**

Comment: excuse me, $\dfrac{41}6 $ is what???

Comment: the total candies over the total kids.

Comment: I was questioning your subsequent computation

Comment: I wrote some as sums instead of mixed numbers.

Comment: I think you meant $\dfrac{41}6=6+\dfrac56$

Comment: Thanks for the catch. my brain turns off at times.

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach might be the right one. Let me know.
$$n_{candies}=\frac{1}{2.5}\times\biggl(\frac{5}{1}+\frac{11}{2}+\frac{25}{3}\biggr)=\frac{30+33+50}{2.5\times6}=\frac{113}{15}=7.533333333333333$$

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer, why 1/2.5?